# Trying to check similarity of 2 columns full of strings with Python and Pysimilar or DamerauLevenshtein

Tags: python, similarity, levenshtein-distance

I tried to summarize texts with a summarizer! The problem is that I would like to see if these texts are too similar, to do this I could read on google that I could use packages like pysimilar or fastDamerauLevenstein.... the problem and that **they seem to work only 1 text only**... Would you know how to do it for example **4 texts or more?**

````
from summarizers import Summarizers 
summ = Summarizers() 
data = ["The NN-CS89L offers next-level cooking convenience. Its four distinct cooking methods - steaming, baking, grilling and microwaving ensure your meals are cooked or reheated to perfection. Its multi-function capabilities can be combined to save time without compromising taste, texture or nutritional value. It’s the all-in-one kitchen companion designed for people with a busy lifestyle.", "These slim and stylish bodies are packed with high performance. The attractive compact designs and energy-saving functions help Panasonic Blu-ray products consume as little power as possible. You can experience great movie quality with this ultra-fast booting DMP-BD89 Full HD Blu-ray disc player. After starting the player, the time it takes from launching the menu to playing a disc is much shorter than in conventional models. The BD89 also allows for smart home networking (DLNA) and provides access to video on demand, so that home entertainment is more intuitive, more comfortable, and lots more fun."] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['summaries'])
df['abstracts'] = df['summaries'].apply(summ)


compare(df.summaries, df.abstracts) ``` 




I have this : 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-d1d78dc1f358> in <module>
----> 1 compare(df.summaries, df.abstracts)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysimilar\__init__.py in compare(self, string_i, string_j, isfile)
     89 
     90         if not isinstance(string_i, (str, Path)) or not isinstance(string_j, (str, Path)):
---> 91             raise TypeError(
     92                 'Both string i and string j must be of type either string or Path')
     93 

TypeError: Both string i and string j must be of type either string or Path

Thanks in advance !
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a function that takes in a row with two columns of values, and calls `compare` on both of them, then apply it to the dataframe.

```
def compare_row_wise(row):
    return compare(row['summaries'], row['abstracts'])

df.apply(compare_row_wise, axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes but that function is with the package pysimilar ?

Comment: Because it gives me nearly the same awnser TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-92eacf806f5b> in <module>
      2     return compare(row['summaries'], row['abstracts'])
      3 
----> 4 df.apply(compare_row_wise, axis=1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7546             kwds=kwds,
   7547         )
-> 7548         return op.get_result()
   7549 
   7550     def applymap(self, func) -> "DataFrame":

Comment: ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysimilar\__init__.py in compare(self, string_i, string_j, isfile)
     89 
     90         if not isinstance(string_i, (str, Path)) or not isinstance(string_j, (str, Path)):
---> 91             raise TypeError(
     92                 'Both string i and string j must be of type either string or Path')
     93 

TypeError: Both string i and string j must be of type either string or Path